# question about the conditional error term in linear regression

Tags: probability

Suppose we are given $n$ i.i.d. random vectors $\{ y_i,X_i \}$ where $y_i$ is a random scalar and $X_i$ is a random vector. Further suppose that $\epsilon_i$ is a linear function of $\{ y_i,X_i \}$. Now, how do I show

$$
\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_i\mid {\bf X}]=\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_i\mid { X_i}]?
$$
where $\bf X$ is the random vector $(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)$

My attempt:

Since $\epsilon_i$ is a linear function of $\{ y_i,{X_i} \}$, we note that $\epsilon_i$ is independent of each random vector $\{ y_j,{X_j} \}$ where $j\neq i$. Now, I feel like I need to show $\epsilon_i$ is independent of the random vector $$\left( \{ y_1,{X_1} \},\{ y_2,{X_2}\},\dots,\{ y_{i-1},{X_{i-1}}\},\{ y_{i+1},{X_{i+1}}\},\dots ,\{ y_{n},{X_{n}}\}\right).$$ However, I know that merely know each component random vector of this big random vector is each independent of $\epsilon_i$ is not a sufficient condition for $\epsilon_i$ to be independent of this huge vector. Hints are appreciated.

Actually, this problem is in the context of classical linear regression model.

Comment: by "i.i.d." don't you mean the $(y_i,X_i)$ are mutually (not just pairwise) independent? Are you familiar with the fact that for random variables $a,b,c$, $E[a|b,c]=E[a|b]$ when $c$ is independent of both $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @snarfblaat Actually, thank you for pointing out the difference between mutually and pairwise indepence, I missed that. So if they are mutually independent, my concern should be addressed. I am not familiar with the fact you mentioned in the last sentence though, how should I proceed?

Comment: are you trying to proceed without using the fact I mentioned in the last sentence, or did you want a proof of that fact? I think your problem is not much less general than the fact as I gave it, so proving the general case ($\epsilon_i$ not restricted to be linear) might be unavoidable.

Comment: @snarfblaat It will be great if you can post a proof of the fact you mentioned. I can't seem to prove it on my own. Thanks!

Comment: I can try, but it will be important for whoever answers to know if you are using the measure theoretic/radon-nikodym definition of the conditional expectation $E[y|X]$, and if not, how are you defining it?

Comment: @snarfblaat I think it is fine to use measure theoretic definition. I don't get all the measure theory, but I will try to understand it. I feel like many econometrics books just assume results proved using measure theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property mentioned in the comment is that $E[A|B,C]=E[A|B]$ when $C$ is independent of $A,B$. By definition, $E[A|B,C]$ is the a.s. unique random variable $Y$ s.t. for any $g\in\sigma(B,C)$, $E[Y1_g]-E[A1_g]=0$. So we want to show that $E[E[A|B]1_g]-E[A1_g]=0$ for any such $g$. In fact we don't need to check any $g$ in $\sigma(B,C)$ but can take a suitable subset, and something like $\pi-\lambda$ theorem or monotone class theorem extends to all of $\sigma(B,C)$. So I will just look at $g$ of the form $b\cap c$ for $b\in\sigma(B),c\in\sigma(C)$. Then $$
E[E[A|B]1_{b\cap c}]=E[E[A|B]1_b1_c]=E[E[A1_b|B]1_c]=E[E[A1_b|B]E[1_c]=E[A1_b]E[1_c]=E[A1_b1_c]=E[A1_{b\cap c}].
$$